# OpenMaya API (python): print more useful info from MObjects? E.g. MFloatVector(x, y, z)

Tags: python, maya

With regular python objects, it is easy to see their details.
E.g.

```
vec = (1, 2, 3)
print vec
```

=>

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

When working with equivalent OpenMaya (OM) objects, all print or str() shows is the type of object:

```
vec = OpenMaya.MFloatVector(1,2,3)
print vec
```

=>

```
<maya.OpenMaya.MFloatVector; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'MFloatVector *' at 0x000000002A346060> >
```

Is there a general way to ask an MObject to provide more details?
I'd like a result something like:

```
MFloatVector(1, 2, 3)
```

----- **EDIT** -----

From C++ documentation, I see that the information I want is available in C++ via the ostream << operator. E.g. for MFloatVector's << it says:

> The format used is [x, y, z]

So another way to ask my question is: In python, how do I create an ostream in memory, send the object to it, then get the result as a string?

----- **EDIT #2** -----

My import statement is:

```
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya
```

This means I am using Version 1 of Maya Python API. (Because some of the Version 2 stuff is stubs, such as MGlobal. Examples I am looking at use these Version 1 features, so I stayed with Version 1.)

I've posted my own answer, which is to use Version 2, to get the desired behavior. TBD whether Version 2 has everything needed, and what is required to convert Version 1 examples to Version 2. For now, I'm sticking to Version 1. If anyone has a way to get Version 1 to provide more useful print details, that is what I would accept as an answer.

Comment: Swig is tricky. Since it's implementing an abstraction layer, Python itself has no idea what properties are stored in the underlying c++ object. See http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn29 . You'll have to iterate the Vector to see which elements it contains.

Comment: @VooDooNOFX See my EDIT: I realize PYTHON doesn't know, but the underlying C++ object does have the ability to print the info I desire, using << to an ostream. Is there some way to make use of that? (I wonder why SWIG doesn't invoke the object's << method, when "print" is applied to the object?)

Comment: Like all python objects, it supports iteration. See http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2013/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/index.html?url=python-api/MFloatVector.html,topicNumber=python_api_MFloatVector_html. (See `Sequence Support` section). Something like `'MFloatVector("{0}")'.format(u', '.join(x for x in vec))` might work for your purposes.

Comment: @VooDooNOFX Thanks - with added "str(x)": 'MFloatVector({0})'.format(u', '.join(str(x) for x in vec)) -- Is there a way to list the attribute names also? (x: 1, y: 2, z: 3)

Comment: Answering my own question: "dir(vec)" lists attributes of vec. (Where vec is any python object.)

Comment: Darn, that doesn't do it for an MObject: I'm getting back a bunch of attributes (from the SWIG proxy?), but that list does not include x, y, or z.

Comment: You won't get the x, y z items here. Instead, when iterating the MFloatVector, you'll get back the items as positional values. You can assign it easily this way: `'MFloatVector(x: {0}, y: {1}, z: {2})'.format([x for x in vec])`

Comment: @VooDooNOFX thanks, but not what I'm looking for. Recall that my question is whether there is a GENERAL way to get details from MObjects. If I wanted formatted output for something I knew was an MFloatVector, that would have been an easy task :)

Comment: BTW, dir(vec) does work on MFloatVector -- I had inadvertently overwritten my vec with a different object that lacked x, y, z. Of course, it also gives me lots of other attributes, such as "isParallel", and all the statics (xAxis). So I'll stick with just getting the 3 values, without names.

Comment: IMPORTANT: "maya.api.OpenMaya" (Version 2 of Python API) has MFloatVector as a sequence (x, y, z) ~AND~ doing "print vec" returns "(1, 2, 3) in my example. Making all this moot. "maya.OpenMaya" (Version 1 of Python API), which is what I was using, does not. No "len(vec)". No useful print info. Attempting to access an MFloatVector from Version 1 as a sequence (e.g. "for x in vec") HANGS MAYA when I try it. Further investigation shows it is in an infinite loop, returning the z value over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code that defines "Repr(self)". A global function that returns "repr(self)" for most objects. But for objects that return a representation starting with "<", the result is a list of member values that (1) aren't internal (don't start with '__'), and (2) aren't methods.

E.g. an OpenMaya MFloatVector instance "OpenMaya.MFloatVector( 1, 2, 3)" gives result:

```
#MFloatVector( x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0)
```

The code:

```
# ==================== AttributeAccess.py ====================
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel
import sys
import maya.OpenMaya as OM        # Version 1
import math

import inspect
import types

# ---------- Common Stuff ----------

# "something" can be any Python object.
def Exists(something):
    return something is not None

def printElements(ob):
    print '----- Elements: -----'
    i = 0
    for x in ob:
        print ' [' + str(i) + ']:  ' + repr(x)
        i += 1
    print '---------------------'

def printDictElements(ob):
    print ''
    print '-----------------------'
    for x in ob: print repr(x) + ':  ' + repr(ob[x])
    print '-----------------------'


# ---------- inspect Attributes ----------

# NOTE: ob is an instance, NOT a type object.
def TypeName(ob):
    return ob.__class__ .__name__

# Excludes 'internal' names (start with '__').
def Public(name):
    return not name.startswith('__')

# member is element of inspect.getmembers:
#   a two-element tuple.
def MemberWithType(member):
    return ( member[0], TypeName(member[1]), member[1] )
#print MemberWithType( (1.1, 2) )

def Members(ob):
    return inspect.getmembers(ob)

# True for Maya Python's 'this' member.
# member [1] is attribute value.
def SwigThis(member):
    return (member[0] == 'this') and (TypeName(member[1]) == 'SwigPyObject')

# HACK: "not SwigThis": omit Maya Python's 'this' member.
def PublicMembers(ob):
    members = filter(lambda member: Public(member[0]) and not SwigThis(member), Members(ob))
    return map(MemberWithType, members)

# Excludes 'internal' names (start with '__').
def Dir(ob):
    return filter(Public, dir(ob))


def _Type_And_Features(ob, names):
    return '{0}.({1})'.format(TypeName(ob), ', '.join(names))

def MemberName(member):
    return member[0]

# member with typename inserted as [1]. So descriptor is [2].
# member type-name is [1].
def CallableMember(member):
    #return (member[2].__class__  is types.MethodType)
    return inspect.isroutine(member[2])

def MemberNames(members):
    return map(MemberName, members)

def Features(ob):
    return _Type_And_Features(ob, MemberNames(PublicMembers(ob)) )   
    #return _Type_And_Features(ob, Dir(ob))

def Callable(ob):
    return _Type_And_Features(ob, MemberNames(filter(lambda a: CallableMember(a), PublicMembers(ob))))
    #return _Type_And_Features(ob, filter(lambda a: callable(a), Dir(ob)))

def IsClassVar(self, attrName):
    return hasattr(self.__class__, attrName)

# REQUIRE attrName already known to be supported by self.
# But just in case, return False if exception, so will be skipped.
def IsNotSameAsClassVar(self, attrName):
    try:
        if not IsClassVar(self, attrName):
            return True
        # If it has different value than class' attribute, it is on the instance.
        return getattr(self, attrName) is not getattr(self.__class__, attrName)
    except:
        return False

# ---------- _MayaValues ----------

# NOTE: 'ob' is an instance, not the class (type) itself.
def _ClassVars(ob):
    attributes = filter(lambda a: not CallableMember(a), PublicMembers(ob))
    # Keep class variables.
    # "not IsProperty": HACK: Skip Maya/Swig 'property' class variables.
    classVars = filter(lambda desc: IsClassVar(ob, desc[0]) and not IsProperty(getattr(ob.__class__, desc[0])), attributes)
    return MemberNames(classVars)

# NOTE: 'ob' is an instance, not the class (type) itself.
def ClassVars(ob):
    return _Header_And_Values(TypeName(ob) + ' Class_Variables',
        map(lambda attr: attr + ': ' + Repr(getattr(ob, attr)), _ClassVars(ob)),
        0
        )


# If it is invocable without parameters, return (attrName, typename, result of invocation).
# if Not reportExceptions, return None for Exception.
def CallAttribute_AsTriple(self, attrName, reportExceptions=False):
    try:
        expressionString = 'self.{0}()'.format(attrName)
        result = eval(expressionString)
        typename = TypeName(result)
    except Exception as e:
        if reportExceptions:
            result = e
            typename = '*** Exception'
        else:
            return None
    return (attrName, typename, result)

# member is tuple (attrName, typeName, value)
# If it is invocable without parameters, return (attrName, typename, result of invocation).
# if Not reportExceptions, return None for Exception.
def CallMember_AsTriple(self, member, reportExceptions=False):
    return CallAttribute_AsTriple(self, member[0], reportExceptions)

# If it is invocable without parameters, return string: pretty-printed result of invocation.
# if Not reportExceptions, return None for Exception.
def CallAttribute(self, attrName, reportExceptions=False):
    try:
        #printElements(locals())
        expressionString = 'self.{0}()'.format(attrName)
        #print Eval(expressionString, locals())
        result = eval(expressionString)
        resultString = Repr(result)
        typename = TypeName(result)
    except Exception as e:
        if reportExceptions:
            #result = '*** Exception  ' + str(e)
            result = e
            resultString = str(e)
            typename = '*** Exception'
        else:
            return None
    return ' .{0} {{{1}}}= {2}'.format(attrName, typename, resultString)

# member is tuple (attrName, typeName, value)
# If it is invocable without parameters, return string: pretty-printed result of invocation.
# if Not reportExceptions, return None for Exception.
def CallMemberRepr(self, member, reportExceptions=False):
    return CallAttribute(self, member[0], reportExceptions)

def FirstLine(string):
    lines = string.split('\n')
    if len(lines) > 1:
        return lines[0] + '...'
    return string

def ArgLessRoutines_AsTriples(ob):
    members = PublicMembers(ob)
    members_WithNones = map(lambda member: CallMember_AsTriple(ob, member), members)
    # member is tuple (attrName, typeName, value)
    members = filter(Exists, members_WithNones)
    return members

def ArgLessRoutines(ob):
    members = PublicMembers(ob)
    members_WithNones = map(lambda member: CallMember_AsTriple(ob, member), members)
    # member is tuple (attrName, typeName, value)
    members = filter(Exists, members_WithNones)
    resultStrings = map(lambda string: FirstLine(string), resultStrings)
    return _Header_And_Values(TypeName(ob) + ' ArgLessRoutines', resultStrings)

def _MayaCallables_Common(mayaType):
    try:
        typeName = mayaType.__name__
        if typeName == 'MDagPath':
            return ['fullPathName']
        if typeName == 'MTypeId':
            return ['id']
        if typeName == 'MFnMesh':
            return ['numPolygons', 'numVertices', 'numEdges', 'numFaceVertices']
        if typeName == 'MDagPath':
            return ['fullPathName']
    except Exception as e:
        print e
    return []

def _MayaCallables_Version1(mayaType):
    return _MayaCallables_Common(mayaType)

def _MayaCallables_Version2(mayaType):
    return _MayaCallables_Common(mayaType)

# Names of callable attributes to include in Repr of 'ob'.
# For instances of types in 'maya.OpenMaya'.
def MayaCallables(ob):
    try:
        typ = ob.__class__
        if typ == type:
            return []
        if typ.__module__ == 'maya.OpenMaya':
            return _MayaCallables_Version1(typ)
        if typ.__module__ == 'OpenMaya':
            return _MayaCallables_Version2(typ)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
    return []

# Return (name, typename, value) per maya callable.
def _MayaValues(ob):
    callables = MayaCallables(ob)
    members_WithNones = map(lambda attrName: CallAttribute_AsTriple(ob, attrName), callables)
    members = filter(Exists, members_WithNones)
    return members

# TODO: If all results fit on single line, remove "{typename}" so is more readable.
#def MayaValues(ob):
#    resultStrings = _MayaValues(ob)
#    return _Header_And_Values(TypeName(ob) + ' MayaValues', resultStrings)

# ---------- Attributes ----------
def _AttributeNames(ob):
    attributes = filter(lambda a: not CallableMember(a), PublicMembers(ob))
    # Omit class variables.
    attributes = filter(lambda desc: IsNotSameAsClassVar(ob, desc[0]), attributes)
    return MemberNames(attributes)

def AttributeNames(ob):
    return _Type_And_Features(ob, _AttributeNames(ob))
    #return _Type_And_Features(ob, filter(lambda a: not callable(a), Dir(ob)))

def _Header_And_Values(headerString, valueStrings, maxWidth=100):
    if sum(map(len, valueStrings)) > maxWidth:
        # pretty print, with one value per line.
        return '{0}(\n  {1}\n)'.format(headerString, '\n  '.join(valueStrings))
    return '{0}({1})'.format(headerString, ', '.join(valueStrings))

def _Type_And_Values(ob, valueStrings, maxWidth=100):
    return _Header_And_Values(TypeName(ob), valueStrings, maxWidth)

def AttributeValues(ob):
    return _Type_And_Values(ob, map(lambda attr: str(getattr(ob, attr)), _AttributeNames(ob)))

def Attributes(ob, depth=0):
    # Limit recursion.
    # If deep, don't include MayaValues.
    if depth >= 2:
        return _Type_And_Values(ob, map(lambda attr: attr + ': ' + str(getattr(ob, attr)), _AttributeNames(ob)))
    attributes = map(lambda attr: attr + ': ' + Repr(getattr(ob, attr), depth + 1), _AttributeNames(ob))
    if depth == 0:
        mayaValues = _MayaValues(ob)
        if len(mayaValues) > 0:
            for mayaValue in mayaValues:
                attribute = mayaValue[0] + ': ' + Repr(mayaValue[2])
                attributes.append(attribute)
    return _Type_And_Values(ob, attributes)

def IsProperty(ob):
    return (TypeName(ob) == 'property')

# ---------- Repr ----------
def Repr(ob, depth=0):
    r = repr(ob)
    # Helps avoid undesired recursion.
    if ob.__class__ == type:
        return r
    if (r.__class__ == types.StringType) and (len(r) > 0) and (r.find('<') <> 0):
        # Has a good repr.
        return r
    # Doesn't have a good repr; inspect it instead.
    return '#' + Attributes(ob, depth)

def Eval(expressionString, _locals=locals(), _globals=globals()):
    return str(expressionString) + "= " + str(Repr(eval(expressionString, _globals, _locals)))


# ---------- Testing ----------

# ---------- class Vector ----------
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0):
        self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z
    # Provide useful info for 'repr(self)', 'str(self)', and 'print self'.
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Vector({0}, {1}, {2})'.format(self.x, self.y, self.z)
    # math operators
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y, self.z + other.z)
    # ==
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.__class__ == other.__class__) and \
            (self.x == other.x) and \
            (self.y == other.y) and \
            (self.z == other.z)
    # a simple method
    def ApproximateLength(self):
        return self.x + self.y + self.z
    # list/sequence/iterator support.
    def tolist(self):
        return [self.x, self.y, self.z]
    def __len__(self):
        return 3
        # No need for "next(self)", because we create a list, use its iterator.
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.tolist())
# class variable
Vector.Zero = Vector()

# ---------- inspecting Vector ----------
def Testing_Vector_Attributes():
    #vec = (1, 2, 3)
    #vec = [1, 2, 3]
    #vec = Vector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
    vec = OM.MFloatVector(1, 2, 3)
    print vec
    #for x in vec: print x
    print dir(vec)
    print TypeName(vec)
    print Dir(vec)
    print Features(vec)
    print Callable(vec)
    print '-----------------------'
    printElements(PublicMembers(vec))
    print '-----------------------'
    print AttributeNames(vec)
    #print vec.x
    #print eval('vec.x')
    #print getattr(vec, 'x')
    print AttributeValues(vec)
    print Attributes(vec)
    vec = OM.MFloatVector(1, 2, 3)
    #print repr(vec)
    #print Repr('Hi')
    print Repr( (1,2,3) )
    print Repr(vec)
    print ClassVars( Vector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0) )
    print ClassVars( OM.MFloatVector(1, 2, 3) )
    print Eval('OM.MMatrix()')
    print Eval('OM.MMatrix().matrix')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Testing_Vector_Attributes()
```

Answer (score 2):

Version 2 of Maya Python API is more python-friendly.

To access Version 2, change the import statement from

```
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya
```

to

```
import maya.api.OpenMaya as OpenMaya
```

This will require changes to the script, as many methods are tweaked to be more python friendly.

Once this is done, "print vec" and "str(vec)" and "len(vec)" all become useful operations:

```
vec = OpenMaya.MFloatVector(1, 2, 3)
print vec
print str(vec)
print len(vec)
```

=>

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
3
```

Comment: However, as I have indicated in an edit to my question, for now I am sticking with Version 1, to match examples I am copying. I would prefer to have a solution that works with Version 1.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is certainly **possible** to wrap the repr function with your own; something along the lines of:

```
import maya.OpenMaya as om

def repr_MfloatVector(self):
    n = self.__class__.__name__
    return "%s(%r, %r, %r)"%(n, self[0], self[1], self[2])

om.MFloatVector.__repr__ = repr_MfloatVector

vec = om.MFloatVector(1,2,3)
print vec
```

This would affect all future (but not past) MFloatVectors. But why you would go trough such a trouble is another matter. As for working in general for MObjects too much work on this level. However you could try to ask *obj.length()* of each object to determine if its iterable etc etc. so you could get a quite good spread still too much work for not much gain.

Comment: The reason to go to such trouble, is that when debugging, the M- classes don't return useful details. I decided this was a good opportunity to learn some advanced python. Used module inspect.members, filtered out internals that start with '__', and methods, made a "Repr(self)" that examines any object which returns from "repr" a string starting with "<", and replaces with a list of member values. E.g. "MFloatVector( x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0)". Works great. (Then I switched to API Version 2, because V. 1 crashed when I used MFnMesh.anyIntersection. So don't need my solution anymore.)